# What "picture" is Dr Grace referring to?

Tags: avatar

Dr. Grace just woke up from the pod inside the lab:

> Dr Grace: Who's got my goddamn cigarette? Guys! What's wrong with this
> **picture**?

[image]

What "picture" is Dr Grace referring to?

Comment: "What's wrong with this picture" is a figure of speech, which you also hear in the movie _The Terminator._

Comment: This probably would have been better asked on English Language and Usage SE or even ELL.

Comment: While I agree that this turns out to just be a question about idiomatic English, [this discussion on the meta site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/is-it-reasonable-to-ask-about-the-meaning-of-phrases-in-a-science-fiction-work) shows a clear consensus that such questions are and should be welcome here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Picture" here can be seen as a synonym for "situation" (listed as [sense 11 of the noun on Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/picture)).

More specifically, though, this is an idiomatic phrase, meaning in this context something like "I'm not happy with this situation, it should be obvious why, and I want you to do something about it". See for example [this US English idiom site](https://idiomwizard.com/whats-wrong-picture/) and [this forum discussion which includes the exact quote you're asking about](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/whats-wrong-with-this-picture.1263306/).

The metaphor is of a puzzle or teaching exercise where you are shown a picture of a situation, and told to spot things that are "not right" in some sense - either deliberate mistakes in the picture itself, or things in the situation depicted that are not following rules of some sort. Saying "something's wrong with this picture" is therefore used to mean "something's wrong with this *situation*".

Phrasing it as a question, along with the emphatic "guys!", reinforces the message that the other person should already have spotted the problem. It's a *rhetorical* question - the speaker is not expecting a direct answer, but action to fix the situation.

Comment: @Valorum I'm struggling to find a decent reference with more than a simple gloss of the meaning, but I've added the page you found plus a forum discussing the usage and origin, as well as a Wiktionary reference for "picture" as "situation" in a more general sense.

Comment: That definitely gets the +1 from me. This isn't ELL, so a basic meaning (plus ref) is more than sufficient